# Using Electron's ipcRender from inside a React component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, electron

I am trying to create a small **React** app that captures and sets a global shortcut, that will be used to show and hide the **Electron** app window. However I have become stuck, as when I try to use **ipcRender**, from inside a **React** component, the following error is thrown.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs"
```

I am using **Webpack** to bundle my JS and compile JSX, and **ES6** syntax to import **Electron** and **ipcRender**, as you can see in my component code below.

```
import React from "react";
import electron, { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

var event2string = require('key-event-to-string')({});

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {shortcut: this.props.globalShortcut[0]};
    },
    handleOnKeyDown:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var keys = event2string(e);
        this.setState({shortcut:keys});

        this.props.globalShortcut.splice(0, 1);
        this.props.globalShortcut.push(keys);
    },
    handleOnKeyUp:function(){
        this.refs.shortcutInput.value = this.state.shortcut;
        this.refs.shortcutInput.blur();
        ipcRenderer.send('set-new-shortcut', this.props.globalShortcut);
    },
    handleOnFocus:function(){
        this.refs.shortcutInput.value = '';
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="settings-container">
                <h1>The show/hide shortcut is "{this.state.shortcut}"</h1>
                <form role="form">
                    <input type="text" ref="shortcutInput" placeholder="Create new shortcut" onFocus={this.handleOnFocus} onKeyDown={this.handleOnKeyDown} onKeyUp={this.handleOnKeyUp} className="form-control form-field"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I've tried different solutions, such as adding a **node-loader** & **json-loader** to my **Webpack** file , adding the node object with **fs** set to 'empty', including a plugin that tells **Webpack** to ignore **fs** and **ipc** and install **fs** via npm. I can't get any of them to work.

Unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge of **Webpack** or **ES6** syntax to figure out what's going on, and most of the solutions I've tried have been in a 'paste-and-hope' fashion. So if anyone could explain, in laymen's terms what's happening, I'll be able to dig some more.

Below is my current **Webpack** file.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/src/js',
  entry: "./index.js",

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/build/'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/, query:{presets:['es2015','react']} },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader' }
    ]
  },

  // Don't know if below is working, 'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs"' error still thrown when trying to import electron
  plugins: [ 
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("^(fs|ipc)$"))
  ],

  // Don't know if below is working, 'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs"' error still thrown when trying to import electron
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Comment: `fs` is a module. Try importing/requiring

Comment: I just tried adding `import fs from 'fs';` before `import electron, { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';` and the error is still thrown. I also tried it with **fs** installed via npm --save-dev.

Comment: This is where the error is taking place in my bundle.js `var _fs = __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"fs\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `target: 'electron-renderer'` in your Webpack config, if you still have issues after that take a look at https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

Comment: This has worked! But has stopped my local dev enviroment from working. I'll have a look through the electron-react-boilerplate github to see why. Could you explain why target: 'electron-renderer' is required or point me to an article that does?

Comment: @adotellison I don't think the official documentation covers it, but [this module](https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer) was the way to do it before the Electron targets were integrated into Webpack proper. I've never used Webpack myself, so can't really explain the why or how, I can just point you in the right direction since I've answered this question more times than I care to remember.

Answer (score 0):

By using [contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/context-bridge) we can resolve this issue

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Notification } = require("electron");

new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

//example to display notification
ipcMain.on('notify', (_, message) => {
   new Notification({title: 'Notification', body: message}).show();
})
```

preload.js

```
const { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  notificationApi: {
    sendNotification(message) {
      ipcRenderer.send('notify', message);
    }
  }
})
```

then using the below code in your reactjs component will trigger a native notification message

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    electron.notificationApi.sendNotification("My custom message!");
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>contextBridge</h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: electron is undefined!

Comment: You can refer this project for the implementation https://github.com/rsathishtechit/webex-desktop